# WordPress wp_list_categories() formatting

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Any ideas on how this can be formatted to print out extra attributes in the `wp_list_categories()` function?

At the moment, this functions returns the following values:

```
  <ul class="projects">

       <li class="wp-post"><a href="category/projects">Projects</a></li>

  </ul>
```

How can I change this function to out put `'id'` and `'title'` tags for both `'li'` and `'a'` elements?

Is there a file somewhere that this can be directly edited or do I need to find a plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `get_categories()` function will retrieve a list of all the categories and their properties, which you can loop through and output your own HTML.

See [the `get_categories` documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) for an example.

Comment: nice one richie, i'll look in to this, it certainly looks more like what i need.